# Include jasmine-sinon to karma

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, sinon

I have this matchers file which I would like to include in karma:

link: https://github.com/froots/jasmine-sinon

I'm using jasmine and sinon. I don't think this plugin is supported by karma. Can I manually configure it somehow?

I tried to add it in config files but karma didn't pick it

```
files: [
      'bower_components/jasmine-sinon.js' //Added it here ???
      'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
      'bower_components/underscore/underscore.js',
      'bower_components/backbone/backbone.js',
      'app/js/*.js'
    ],
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma

Comment: If nothing else works you can always load this file dynamically. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file

Answer (score 0):

you will need to have it point directly to the file, in this case, the correct path should be `bower_components/jasmine-sinon/lib/jasmine-sinon.js`.